Terraform: Error: retrieving static website properties for Storage Account (Subscription: *** : context deadline exceeded
When I am deploying Azure Storage account using terraform, I am getting error like - Error: retrieving static website properties for Storage Account (Subscription: *** : context deadline exceeded.
When I am removing the code for private endpoint creation, the Storage account is getting deployed. But when I am using all the code together for storage account and private endpoint, my pipeline is failing with above error mentioned.
I removed the code for private endpoint and the storage account got created. Then post that I added the code for private endpoint and private endpoint got created. But why it is not getting created when I have both the codes together for storage account and private endpoint.

Sometimes (not always) this issue is due to stale entries in the client DNS cache or DNS propagation delays.  Can you reproduce the issue on your local workstation (instead of running it via the pipeline)?  If so and it's feasible, try this from your local workstation: destroy your Terraform config (assuming that's ok to do), then run nslookup on the storage account hostname multiple times until no DNS record is found.  Then, redeploy your configuration.

The context deadline exceeded occurs when the request made by Terraform takes longer than the default timeout value. You can try increasing the timeout value to resolve this issue. You can do this by setting the timeouts block in the azurerm_storage_account resource, using
timeouts {
create = "30m"
update = "30m"
delete = "30m"
}
,Refer the link for same issue


Terraform: Error: retrieving static website properties for Storage Account (Subscription: *** : context deadline exceeded

The context deadline exceeded occurs when the request made by Terraform takes longer than the default timeout value. You can try increasing the timeout value to resolve this issue. when the storage account is created, it might not be immediately ready to accept a private endpoint connection, leading to errors.
To address this issue, you can add a depends_on attribute for the azurerm_private_endpoint resource and add timeout block in the storage account block. This ensures that it waits until the null_resource.log_enabler is fully executed, thereby ensuring that the storage account is completely set up before the private endpoint creation begins
Here is the updated Terraform code to create a storage account, a private endpoint, and other resources in a single run.
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name = "RG_Name"
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "example" {
  name                = "mydomain.com"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "storage-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  depends_on = [azurerm_private_dns_zone.example]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "storage-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
  service_endpoints    = ["Microsoft.Storage"]


  depends_on = [azurerm_virtual_network.example]
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "saflow" {
  name                     = "thejastorage"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  min_tls_version          = "TLS1_2"
  allow_nested_items_to_be_public = false
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
  timeouts {
    create = "30m"
    update = "30m"
    delete = "30m"
  }

  blob_properties {
    delete_retention_policy {
      days = 30
    }
    container_delete_retention_policy {
      days = 30
    }
    versioning_enabled = true
  }

  queue_properties {
    logging {
      delete                = true
      read                  = true
      write                 = true
      version               = "1.0"
      retention_policy_days = 10
    }
    hour_metrics {
      enabled                   = true
      include_apis              = true
      retention_policy_days     = 10
      version                   = "1.0"
    }
    minute_metrics {
      enabled                  = true
      include_apis             = true
      retention_policy_days    = 10
      version                  = "1.0"
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_container" "container" {
  name                  = "thejacontainer"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.saflow.name
  container_access_type = "private"
  depends_on = [azurerm_storage_account.saflow]
}

resource "null_resource" "log_enabler" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
    az storage account keys list --account-name ${azurerm_storage_account.saflow.name} --resource-group ${azurerm_storage_account.saflow.resource_group_name} --query '[0].value' --output tsv > key.txt
    az storage logging update --log rwd --retention 30 --services qtb --account-name ${azurerm_storage_account.saflow.name} --account-key $(cat key.txt)
    rm key.txt
    EOT
  }

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_storage_container.container
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "endpoint" {
  name                = "storageendpoint"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.example.id

  private_dns_zone_group {
    name                 = "storagedns"
    private_dns_zone_ids = [azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.id]
  }

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "storageconnection"
    is_manual_connection           = false
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_storage_account.saflow.id
    subresource_names              = ["blob"]
  }

  depends_on = [null_resource.log_enabler]
}

provider "azurerm" {
  alias    = "globalsub"
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_a_record" "recordglobal" {
  name                = azurerm_storage_account.saflow.name
  zone_name           = azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  ttl                 = 10
  records             = [azurerm_private_endpoint.endpoint.private_service_connection[0].private_ip_address]
  depends_on = [azurerm_private_endpoint.endpoint]
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account_network_rules" "networkrule" {
  storage_account_id         = azurerm_storage_account.saflow.id
  default_action             = "Deny"
  virtual_network_subnet_ids = [azurerm_subnet.example.id]
  bypass                     = ["AzureServices"]
  depends_on = [azurerm_private_dns_a_record.recordglobal]
}

Terraform apply

Portal result

Refer the link to resolve Context Deadline Exceeded Error

Still getting the same error message -
Error: retrieving static website properties for Storage Account (Subscription: "***"
Resource Group Name: "rg-name"
Storage Account Name: "saflow"

Kindly delete the state file and use my code to create a storage account and Private endpoint at same time.

Hi @lzzy, I hope this helps you resolve the issue. Let me know if you are still facing an error.

Hello Venkat, Thanks a lot for your help. This code worked for me. Now the pipeline is successful.

You are experiencing issues what is caused by the underlying design of Azure APIs and the AzureRM provider for Terraform. There is extensive discussion on the topic here.
The problem: you are executing Terraform from a network that does not have network connectivity to the private endpoint of that storage account AND you have not allowed your public IP address to access the storage account.
Possible solution 1: You grant a firewall exception to the public IP where you are executing your Terraform from. Might be against the security requirements you are working with
Possible solution 2 You execute your terraform in a place, that has visibility to the private endpoint (e.g. a VM running in the same VNET, through a VPN or similar)
Notes: This is not a timeout issue, the request just says timeout as its blocked by the blob storage Firewall. Also the first Terraform always succeeds as Terraform just notices that there is no existing Blob Storage -> no need to refresh its status.

To be exhaustive of all situations that can give you this error.
My environment used a

Microsoft Agent
Azure Private DNS
Azure Private Endpoints

Code Snippet
module "data-lake-gen2" {
  source = "./modules/datalake"

  region                           = var.rg-location
  resource_group_name              = var.rg-name
  storage_account_name             = var.data-lake-storage-name
  storage_account_replication_type = var.storage_account_replication_type
  blob_soft_delete_retention_days = var.blob_soft_delete_retention_days
  datalake-diag-name              = var.datalake-diag-name

  
  depends_on = [module.dp-rg, module.dp-vnet]

}

module "datalake-private-endpoint" {
  source = "./modules/private-endpoint"

  pe_resource_group_name = var.rg-name
  private_endpoint_name  = var.datalake-private-endpoint
  subresource_names      = ["blob"]
  # endpoint_resource_id   = module.data-lake-gen2.storage_account_id # have to manually use the resource ID to address the race condition
  endpoint_resource_id = var.datalake-endpoint-id
  pe_subnet_id         = module.dp-vnet.vnet_subnet_id[0]
  location             = var.rg-location
  private_ip_address   = var.datalake_private_ip_address
  member_name          = var.datalake_member_name
  subresource_name     = var.datalake_subresource_name


  dns = {
    zone_ids  = [module.dns.dns_zone_ids[1]]
    zone_name = var.dns_zone_names[1]
  }

  depends_on = [module.dp-resourcegroup, module.dp-vnet]
}

The code had no problems and worked as expected. The customer wanted to secure their environment by deploying through a SELF HOSTED AGENT.
When I switched to a Self Hosted Agent, I then got this error error.
Error message
    Error: retrieving static website properties for Storage Account (Subscription: "xxxxxxxx"
│ Resource Group Name: "rg-ae-01"
│ Storage Account Name: "stxxxxxe01"): executing request: Get "https://stxxxxxe01.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=properties&restype=service": context deadline exceeded
│ 
│   with module.data-lake-gen2.azurerm_storage_account.this,
│   on modules/datalake/main.tf line 40, in resource "azurerm_storage_account" "this":
│   40: resource "azurerm_storage_account" "this" {

Solution
The problem was the race condition between the datalake and the private endpoint. Terraform was trying to create the datalake, it was also trying to lookup the storage endpoints using a non existent private endpoint connected to the internal private DNS.
My Solution was to pass the actual ID of the endpoint_resource_id because deploying the private endpoint depended on the datalake being created first and the datalake depended on the private endpoint being created first.
  # endpoint_resource_id   = module.data-lake-gen2.storage_account_id 
  # have to manually use the resource ID to address the race condition
  endpoint_resource_id = var.datalake-endpoint-id

variables.tfvars
   datalake-endpoint-id = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/rg-xxx-ae-01/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/stasdsdsdse01"

